# How to find velocity perpendicular to a slope when the approach velocity is at an angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say a slope is inclined in the direction$$(-i + 3j)$$ and a ball with velocity $$(2i + 1.5j)$$ is approaching.

What methods could be used to determine the components of the velocity perpendicular and parallel to the slope?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iyRp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem can be easily solved by using the vector [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The component of the velocity parallel to the slope is given by
$$(2i+1.5j)\cdot\left(\frac{-i+3j}{||-i+3j||}\right)$$
and perpendicular to the slope (i.e. parallel to $3i+j$) is given by
$$(2i+1.5j)\cdot\left(\frac{3i+j}{||3i+j||}\right)$$
An explanation for this is that
$$a\cdot \left(\frac{b}{||b||}\right)=||a||\,\left|\left|\frac{b}{||b||}\right|\right|\cos{(\theta)}=||a||\cos{(\theta)}$$
which is equivalent to the component of $a$ in the direction of $b$ as $\cos{(\theta)}$ can be found by the ratio of the parallel component of $a$ with the magnitude of $a$.

Comment: This is great. How do you know how to get the perpendicular velocity of 3i + j from -i + 3j?

Comment: In two dimensions, the vector perpendicular to $ai+bj$ is $k(bi-aj)$. You can check this by performing a dot product between the two vectors in which case you will get $0$.

Comment: But the dot product will just give a scalar value so how is this a component of velocity?

Comment: This is the magnitude of the component in each direction. If you want the vector equivalent you need to multiply this component by the unit vector in the given direction.